# JavaScript got data from array via [ index ] instead of ( index )

Tags: javascript, arrays, solidity, hardhat

in javascript and in solidity if you need to get gata from array index you can write like that
`let data = array[ index ]`
but in the testing phase, i saw javascript got data from array like this `array ( index )`

> my array in solidity `address[] public funders;`

while testing in hardhat  via JS

```
 it("add funders to array funders array", async () => {
        await fundMe.fund({ value: sendValue })
        let funder = await fundMe.funders(0)

        assert.equal(funder, deployer)
    })
```

array works like that `array [ index ]` but how is this working. ?????
it shows error if i use `[ ]` to get data from array.

[image: image (6)]

Comment: I bet `funMe.funders` is a FUNCTION - not only that, but I bet that function returns a PROMISE

Comment: "*array works like that array [ index ] but how is this working. ????? it shows error if i use [ ] to get data from array.*" doesn't that suggest to you that it's *not* an array? If it doesn't walk like a duck, and it doesn't quack like a dug, and literally throws an error if you try to treat it like a duck, it might not be a duck.

Comment: @JaromandaX maybe you are right, but i don't have any function in `fundMe` contract of named `funders` actually this is the `array in fundMe` contract

Comment: @TalhaRafique solidity creates getter functions for all `public` variables automatically, with the same name as the variable